# Should i use Entity Framework entities in my presentation layer?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, design-patterns

I want to create a multi layered (3 layers) application. EF is the preferred ORM of choice.

Should i use the entities that EF creates directly in my presentation layer, or should i create new custom entities and map the entities? If so, should i create interfaces on top of the custom entitie?

Should i place the .edmx file that EF generates in the data layer?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally I'd create ViewModels for my presentation layer. You want to keep your EF models abstracted away as best as possible.

You wouldn't need any interfaces for your ViewModels, they're just simple [POCO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_Old_CLR_Object)/[DTO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object)s.

Comment: Should i place the .edmx file that EF generates in the data layer?

Comment: And do you place the ViewModels in the business layer?

Comment: The way I do it, my business layer returns custom objects so that I can abstract my data layer models as soon as possible. I create the ViewModels at the controller level (most of my work is Web based using ASP.NET MVC) and I pass these to my views. So the method that passes data directly to the presentation layer is where I create the ViewModels however in your case the presentation layer is probably the place to create ViewModels.

Comment: ViewModels go in your UI layer, if you had entities that represented major concept objects of the business, those would go into a BLL. EF would go into DAL. Say you have a financial app, getting the data is the responsibility of the DAL, and that's where EF belongs. Business entities like an Account, AccountHolder, etc would have business rules and state and those objects would read the DAL by passing DTOs back and forth (POCOs) for fast data transfer. The UI would create entities and aggregate them into complex objects that represent multiple pieces of entities, those become your ViewModels

Comment: @JamieDixon this is for MVC too. So do you create your ViewModels on the controller level (which is presentation layer), or do you just call a method from your controller that gets the necessary entities and maps them to a ViewModel, which you send back to the presentation layer?

Comment: Well, I like things being structured so I actually create converters. I have an interface IConverter<TFrom,TTo> from which I create a specific converter interface IMyObjectToMyObjectViewModelConverter. IConverter defines a TTo Invoke(TFrom) method and I inject the converter into my controller. Before re-factoring my code out into a converter I just return a new viewmodel object in my controller method.

Comment: @CDSmith
Im using ASP.NET MVC. From what i can understand, the Controller (presentation layer) is supposed to do the mapping between objects from the business layer (DTO/POCO) and ViewModels? Jamie, do you have some pseudocode of your converter ? :) The ViewModel that i need is put together from three different objects. Would i then have to pass all theese three objects to the presentation layer and create the ViewModel there? For me it just seems nicer to do it in the BLL

Comment: I'm using MVC 3 as well. And yes, my controller create my BLL entities, map them to ViewModels, and then send that model to View.

Comment: I posted an answer with some code samples showing an index page that loads a record using an entity and mapping it to a ViewModel. A Create which creates a ViewModel that allows the user to create a new record, map the VM to an entity and save. And edit an entity by getting the entity from the db (the entity itself populates itself by getting the record from the db so it's abstracted away from the UI layer) and then maps to a VM and sent to a View and then the return process to save the updates made.

Comment: @Kenci : Your view model is only important to your Views, and so I think it's propper to create it in your controller. Moving that code to your BLL has no benefit for you because later down the line you might need the same VM outside of the scope of your current BLL logic.

Answer (score 2):

The needs of the database and the needs of the data consumer are quite often at odds, and so typically require different models.

For example, consider the User Story of adding a new customer.  The Story typically includes the "need" for an office phone number, and a fax number.

Right away, a database designer will way "That's repeating data" I need a one to many relationship, so that we can accommodate not just two phone numbers but a virtually infinite number of phones, by type.  (and let's not even get into the pain of phone numbers being many-to-many or one-to-many)

Meanwhile back on the report, screen, mobile device, what have you UI experience -- that designer is saying "I don't care how many phone number you are able to store, I'm going to deal with just two: an office number, and a fax number"  You could say that Users are at their core denormalized :)

1. keep your database model true to some sort of reasonable level of
   normalization.
2. let the data model of your user interface be as denormalized as your users
3. develop a layer in the middle that maps one model to the other.

Comment: The problem with your use-case between the developers on the team is that you're assuming there are no requirements management and communication between the teams and the tasks. They're all just solving whatever problem they think is best without thinking about how the software must come together as a whole.

Comment: @DavidAnderson I hear you, but  the difficulty remains competing concerns.  For example, a UI that exposes only a subset of the possibilites made available by the underlying data.  The problem is in reconciling these competing concerns.  I'm simply suggesting that there should be well defined points of interaction between these parties, UI and DB in this case. Where you want to do the mapping is of course open for debate, but unless you're writing nothing more than a simple table editor I would suggest that some sorting of mapping between competing structures is unavoidable.